# magento child category showing parent category showing left or right

Tags: category, navigation

The bottom php code is my website side navigation code(drop down)..and i am hoping after as look showing image !!! . this is possible ? i'm very short english skill please help me !

[image]

navigation

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php if(count($_categories)): ?>

<div class="block block-advancedmenu">
<div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Categories'); ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content" >
    <div id="advancedmenu">
        <?php if ($this->showHomeLink()) : ?>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="parentMenu menu0 home_link">
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif ?>

          <?php $m=0; ?>
         <?php $n=0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <?php $m++; 
            if($m<11){   ?>
            <?php echo $this->drawAdvancedMenuItem($_category) ?>
            <?php }else{ ?>
        <div class="menu seeall">
            <div class="subparentMenu menu0 seeall">
                <div class="subparentmenu-hover">
                <div class="super-sub">
               <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php $n++;
                if($n<11){}else{ ?>
                 <?php echo $this->drawAdvancedMenuItem($_category) ?>
                 <?php } ?>
               <?php endforeach ?>
               </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              
            <?php break;    }?>
        <?php endforeach ?>



        <?php if ($this->isActivecustomBlock()) : 
            $custom_block_name =  Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/customblock/menucustomblock_name'); 
            $custom_block_identifier =  Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/customblock/customblock_identifier'); 
            $custom_topoffset = Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/top_offset') + 0;
        ?>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="custom_menu menu">
                <a><span><?php echo $custom_block_name; ?></span></a>
            <div class="customblock_inner megnor-advanced-menu-popup" style="top:<?php echo $custom_topoffset; ?>px">
                <div class="megnor-advanced-menu-popup_inner">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($custom_block_identifier)->toHtml() ?> 
                </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php  endif;?> 

</div>  <!-- advancedmenu -->   
</div> <!-- block-content -->   

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/width') + 0; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_TOP_OFFSET = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/top_offset') + 0; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_RIGHT_OFFSET_MIN = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/right_offset_min') + 0; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_DELAY_BEFORE_DISPLAYING = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/delay_displaying') + 0; ?>;
var CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_DELAY_BEFORE_HIDING = <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced_menu/popup/delay_hiding') + 0; ?>;
var megnorCustommenuTimerShow = {};
var megnorCustommenuTimerHide = {};
//]]>
</script>
</div><!-- block-advancedmenu -->   
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for but just in case you're seeking some CSS help, here you will find an excellent pure CSS dropdown code example:

http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd